# Wordpress Remove Query Strings with different arguments from Static Resources

Tags: wordpress

I got this code in my Wordpress theme function.php file for removing Query Strings from Static Resources. However, I would like to be able to remove query strings with different arguments as well, like ?v, ?rev. I realize I just could change the "?ver" to "?", but then it would also remove google map URL's like "?pb" which I don't want. How can I add multiple arguments to this code?

```
// Remove Query Strings from Static Resources
function _remove_script_version( $src ){
  $parts = explode( '?ver', $src );
    return $parts[0];
  }

add_filter( 'script_loader_src', '_remove_script_version', 15, 1 );
add_filter( 'style_loader_src', '_remove_script_version', 15, 1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
// Remove Query Strings from Static Resources
function _remove_script_version( $src ){ 
$parts = explode( '?', $src );  
return $parts[0]; 
} 
add_filter( 'script_loader_src', '_remove_script_version', 15, 1 ); 
add_filter( 'style_loader_src', '_remove_script_version', 15, 1 );
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: If you read my question once more, you will see that changing "?ver" to "?" won't solve this issue!

Answer (score 0):

Try below code for remove query string as well in your function.php file:

```
function _remove_script_version( $src ){ 
$parts = explode( '&ver', $src );  
return $parts[0]; 
} 
if (is_admin()) {
}
else{
    add_filter( 'script_loader_src', '_remove_script_version', 15, 1 ); 
    add_filter( 'style_loader_src', '_remove_script_version', 15, 1 );
}
```

Comment: What about "?v", "?rev"?